# Multiple events attached to the same prop (vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

The documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

is not clear (at least to me) about how to attach multiple events to the same component:

In:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-dust-2tno0?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue

is this the right way of emitting multiple events (edit/delete category) bound to the same prop:

```
  <div
    class="modal-body"
    v-bind:taskItem="taskItem"
    @click="$emit('edit-category', $event.target.taskItem)"
  >
    <slot name="name"> Edit Name </slot>
  </div>

  <div
    class="modal-body"
    v-bind:taskItem="taskItem"
    @click="$emit('delete-category', $event.target.taskItem)"
  >
    <slot name="delete"> Delete Category </slot>
  </div>
```

?

Model defined as:

```
  model: {
    prop: "taskItem",
    event: "edit-category",
  },
  props: {
    taskItem: {
      required: true,
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
```

The sample in the docs:

```
Vue.component('base-checkbox', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind:checked="checked"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
  `
})
```

does not explicitly state how to bind more than one event per prop; e.g. something like:

```
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'event-a',
    event: 'event-b',
  },
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a situation where `v-model` makes sense.

`v-model` is just an abstraction for a particular prop and which event will be emitted by the component when that prop value should be updated with a new value. This makes sense for something like an input field which has a `value` prop (a string) and it emits an `input` event with a new value when that binding should be updated.

It doesn't seem like your `taskItem` example fits this structure. `taskItem` is an object. There are two distinct actions that can happen: its category/name can be edited or deleted. You're not replacing the entire `taskItem` object in either of those actions, so this isn't a good fit for `v-model`.

A couple of other things:

- You can't use `v-bind:taskItem` on a `<div>`. `<div>` is not a component and hence does not have a `taskItem` prop to bind to. (Vue would probably attempt to set the `taskItem` attribute on the div to the stringified value of the `taskItem` prop which is not the behavior you want.)
- Your click handler for the `<div>` accesses `$event.target.taskItem` which does not exist (I suppose you thought the `v-bind:taskItem` would make it accessible like that?). `taskItem` is already in scope as a prop on the component so you can just use it as-is.

Comment: Yes, adding `:taskItem` to a bare div was not what I intended. Should probably ask a new question but what's the scope of events in vue? Global? Any component can listen to events from all of its children regardless of depth? Can events work their way down (same as props)?

Comment: Yes it should be a separate question. DOM events can bubble, so you can attach `@click` to a top level `<div>` and it'll receive click events for any of its children. Vue events do not bubble.